# Wrong display of xAxes in Chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I have a strange issue. I'm getting the date from the database. All visualization was good. Then I deleted one record and add another one on the same date and time. But that record moved on the right in the chart instead to be ordered on left:
[image]

The js code is this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "js/json/otv_fil_iskar/data.php",
        method: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var progress = document.getElementById('animationProgress');
            var dateANDtime = [];
            var Gblok9osx = [];
            var Gblok9osy = [];
            var Gblok11osx = [];
            var Gblok11osy = [];
            var Gfilblok10 = [];
            var Gfilblok11 = [];
            var Gcvn = [];
            var Gndk2 = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                dateANDtime.push(data[i].to_char);
                Gblok9osx.push(data[i].blok9osx);
                Gblok9osy.push(data[i].blok9osy);
                Gblok11osx.push(data[i].blok11osx);
                Gblok11osy.push(data[i].blok11osy);
                Gfilblok10.push(data[i].filblok10);
                Gfilblok11.push(data[i].filblok11);
                Gcvn.push(data[i].cvn);
                Gndk2.push(data[i].ndk2);
            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: dateANDtime,
                datasets : [
                    {fill: false,
                        label: 'Отвес блок 9 x',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(199, 228, 238, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(1, 150, 200, 0.75)',
                        //hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: Gblok9osx,
                        hidden: true
                    },
                    {fill: false,
                        label: 'Отвес блок 9 y',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(163, 147, 222, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(50, 10, 200, 0.75)',
                        //hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: Gblok9osy,
                        hidden: true
                    },
                    {fill: false,
                        label: 'Отвес блок 11 x',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(221, 221, 241, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(100, 100, 200, 0.75)',
                        //hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: Gblok11osx,
                        hidden: true
                    },
                    {fill: false,
                        label: 'Отвес блок 11 y',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(147, 227, 227, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(1, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        //hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: Gblok11osy,
                        hidden: true
                    },
                    {fill: false,
                        label: 'Филтрация блок 10',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(139, 105, 132, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 1, 200, 0.75)',
                        //hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: Gfilblok10,
                        hidden: true
                    },
                    {fill: false,
                        label: 'Филтрация блок 11',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 200, 1, 1)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(0, 101,1, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(50, 50, 50, 1)',
                        data: Gfilblok11,
                        hidden: true
                    },
                    {fill: false,
                        label: 'КВН',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(30, 100, 100, 1)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(100, 200,1, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(101, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(50, 50, 50, 1)',
                        data: Gcvn,
                        hidden: false
                    },
                    {fill: false,
                        label: 'Ниво дренажен кладенец',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(30, 100, 100, 1)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(100, 200,1, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(101, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(50, 50, 50, 1)',
                        data: Gndk2,
                        hidden: true
                    }
                ]
            };
            $('#reset_zoom').click(function() {
                barGraph.resetZoom();
            })
            $("#save-btn").click(function() {
                $("#mycanvas").get(0).toBlob(function(blob) {
                    saveAs(blob, "chart_1.png");
                });
            });
            var ctx = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: chartdata,
                options: {
                    title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Диаграма - Отвеси и филтрации'
            },
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: '[mm] , [l/s]'
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:false
                            }
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Дата/Час'
                            },
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                        }]
                    },
                    // Container for pan options
                    pan: {
                        // Boolean to enable panning
                        enabled: true,

                        // Panning directions. Remove the appropriate direction to disable
                        // Eg. 'y' would only allow panning in the y direction
                        mode: 'y'
                    },

                    // Container for zoom options
                    zoom: {
                        // Boolean to enable zooming
                        enabled: true,

                        // Zooming directions. Remove the appropriate direction to disable
                        // Eg. 'y' would only allow zooming in the y direction
                        mode: 'xy'

                    },
                    animation: {
                        duration: 2000,
                        onProgress: function(animation) {
                            progress.value = animation.currentStep / animation.numSteps;
                        },
                        onComplete: function() {
                            window.setTimeout(function() {
                                progress.value = 0;
                            }, 2000);
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                display: true,
                labels: {
                    //fontColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
                                usePointStyle: true
                }
            }
                },
                plugins: [{
                    beforeDraw: function(c) {
                        var reset_zoom = document.getElementById("reset_zoom"); //reset button
                        var ticks = c.scales['x-axis-0', 'y-axis-0'].ticks.length; //x-axis ticks array
                        var labels = c.data.labels.length; //labels array
                        if (ticks < labels) reset_zoom.hidden = false;
                        else reset_zoom.hidden = true;
                    }
                }]
            }); //end data
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

The same think is happening when i don't have records in particular time of the day.

I changed `xAxes` option in the same graph and it's similar output:

```
            xAxes: [{
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            displayFormats: {
              'hour': 'DD MMM YYYY г. HH:MM:SS ч.'
            }
          },
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Дата/Час'
          },
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in the dataset is important because chart.js does not do any sorting of the values. Make sure that you fetch data from the database ordered by date and not id which usually is default.

Comment: Yes, the problem was in the query sorting. Thanks!